# Error using take operator in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular 5.

I'm trying to use rxjs take operator, but get the following error (take located in function 1):
ERROR TypeError: userDoc.collection(...).doc(...).snapshotChanges(...).take is not a function

When located in function 2:
ERROR TypeError: this.getMyMeasurement(...).take is not a function

```
Import section:
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { take } 'rxjs/add/operator/take'; // Don't think this is necessary, since Observable is imported
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { AuthService } from '../../users/services/auth.service';
import { UserdbService } from '../../users/services/userdb.service';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

import { User } from './../../users/models/User';
import { MeasurementLibrary } from '../../library/models/MeasurementLibrary';
import { MyMeasurement } from '../models/MyMeasurement';
import { MyMeasure } from '../models/MyMeasure';

import * as collection from '../../common/collections';
.
.
.
Function 1:
  getMyMeasurement(id: string): Observable<MyMeasurement> {
    const email = this.authService.getLoginUserid();
    const userDoc = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${email}`);
    this.$measurement = userDoc
      .collection<MyMeasurement>(collection.MY_MEASUREMENT)
      .doc(id)
      .snapshotChanges()
      // Have tried here too take(1)
      .map(action => {
        if (action.payload.exists === false) {
          return null;
        } else {
          const data = action.payload.data() as MyMeasurement;
          data.id = action.payload.id;
          return data;
        }
      });

    return this.$measurement;
  }

Function 2:
  updateDateAndMeasure(id: string) {
    this._measurementSubscription2 = this.getMyMeasurement(id)
      .take(1) 
      .subscribe(myMeasurement => {
        this.myMeasurement = myMeasurement as MyMeasurement;

        if (!this.myMeasurement.firstMeasurement) {
          this.myMeasurement.firstMeasurement = new Date();
        }

        this.myMeasurement.numberOfMeasures =
          this.myMeasurement.numberOfMeasures + 1;

        const email = this.authService.getLoginUserid();
        const measurementDoc = this.afs.doc<User>(
          collection.USERS + `/${email}`
        );
        measurementDoc
          .collection<MyMeasurement>(collection.MY_MEASUREMENT)
          .doc(id)
          .update(this.myMeasurement);
      });
  }
```

Comment: The correct way to add an operator is with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @martin says, you're importing the operator incorrectly. It is:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'
```

And it is necessary because, though you're importing `Observable`, it does not include operators by default (so to only add the ones you use to the final package of your application). You don't really import anything, but by just adding that import, the `take` method is added to `Observable.prototype`, and so then you can use it.

Comment: Thanks @martin U made my day! It worked! I was just getting blind looking at the code...I read a comment in some response where they said it was not necessary..

Comment: It can be not necessary, depending on how you're importing rxjs. You can import the whole package via the `Rx` namespace if you want, and then you import *everything*, though it is not a good idea as the size of the RxJS is quite large. Can you please mark the the answer as valid?